# One Solution - MariaDb "cannot create file master.lower-test"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have read many questions about this error with a hundred different solutions. It appears when you try to move your data directory away from /var/lib/mysql. In many cases it was permissions problem or apparmor problem or SELinux problem. In my case the daemon stopped loading in Debian8 after updating to MariaDb v10.?? when my data already worked in /home/michael/mariadb.  Apparmor and SELinux are not used and I double checked all the permissions with no success. After 6 months I decided to solve the problem once and for all and it turned out to be a simple change to 2 files:
/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@.sevice and mariadb.service.
Comment out the line: "ProtectHome=true". This protects the /home /root and /run/user directories from being written to. This may be necessary for some users but it was not included in earlier versions. I prefer to keep my databases in the same partition as my other data for simple.
I am surprised this solution has not been mentioned in any forums including MariaDb!

Comment: Thanks A LOT ! I searched a lot before finding your good solution !

Comment: I ended up doing a bind mount to /var/lib/mysql to get this to work.  (Needed to move mysql database to be able to use it in dual boot win/linux setup on ntfs.)

Comment: Instead of manually editing files, you can also use the following commands to change ProtectHome config value : `systemctl edit --full mariadb.service` and then `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl start mariadb`.